# Redirect to same named page in directory structure before path changes

Tags: redirect, path, http-status-code-404

Well, say I have a number of html pages in my web. The case is that I´m doing changes sometimes in the directory structure, so when anybody try to access to a determinated URL, it's possible that such URL does not exit. The files names don't change but so do the paths.

As far as I now, the server takes the user to a "404" page that can be customized. Is possible to customize the page in this way?:

1. The user tries oneweb.com/oldpath/page.html; which does not exist.
2. A 404 customized page is launched
3. 404 page runs an script IS THIS POSSIBLE?
4. The script is given the name of the file WHERE IS STORED SUCH NAME?
5. The script search the entire directory structure to find page.html HOW TO ACCESS TO THE STRUCTURE
6. The file is found and the new URL is stored: oneweb.com/newpath/page.html
7. a link appears showing the new URL

Maybe this process is relatively common and I can find some related code or tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Apache? Linux?

Add a 404 handler

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Then use 404.php to parse the url. This simple example just grabs everything after the last / in the URI so http://example.com/foo/bar/page.html would put page.html in $url:

```
$url = end(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Then use one of the comment example functions in http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php to search your directory and find the file.

Then do a header 301 redirect

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: http://example.com/' . $file_path);
```

Comment: Lol good point... i didnt even think to ask if he was using something other than .Net and IIS :)

Comment: Great... You just put me in the way. I didn't know php.net; looks very good to me. I use Apache, but already mounted in a free hosting server.